# return single response with validation errors including unique username constraint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to return a single response to a request containing invalid data.

If i duplicate a username (post a username that's already in the base [it's a pk]) then I get the response:

```
{
    "username": [
        "A user with that username already exists."
    ]
}
```

That's great, but if i then select a unique username, and there are other errors in the request, there will be the following response:

```
{
    "gdpr_value_error": [
        "GDPR must be accepted"
    ],
    "role_value_error": [
        "Role must correspond to an existing role"
    ],
    "email": [
        "A user with that email already exists."
    ]
}
```

I want this:

```
{
    "gdpr_value_error": [
        "GDPR must be accepted"
    ],
    "role_value_error": [
        "Role must correspond to an existing role"
    ],
    "email": [
        "A user with that email already exists."
    ],
    "username": [
        "A user with that username already exists."
    ]
}
```

My serializer is:

```
class SeaUserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'role', 'gdpr', 'password',)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        errors_to_return = {}

        if attrs['gdpr'] != True:
            errors_to_return["gdpr_value_error"] = "GDPR must be accepted"

        CAPTAIN = 'cpt'
        CREW = 'crw'
        OTHER = 'oth'
        ROLE_CHOICES = {
            CAPTAIN: _('Captain'),
            CREW: _('Crew'),
            OTHER: _('Other'),
        }

        if attrs['role'] not in ROLE_CHOICES.keys():
            errors_to_return["role_value_error"] = "Role must correspond to an existing role"

        existing_usernames = User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)
        if attrs['username'] in existing_usernames:
            errors_to_return["username"] = "A user with that username already exists."

        existing_emails = User.objects.values_list('email', flat=True)
        if attrs['email'] in existing_emails:
            errors_to_return["email"] = "A user with that email already exists."


        if len(errors_to_return) > 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(errors_to_return)

        return attrs
```

model:

```
class SeaUser(AbstractUser):
    # Constants
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name',]
    # Fields
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'))
    role = models.CharField(_('Role'), max_length=3)
    gdpr = models.BooleanField(_('GDPR'), default=False,)
    preferred_timezone = TimeZoneField(_('Preferred_timezone'), default='UTC',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I've searched for the error message in the class heirachy, but can't find where the verification of username is (and where the error is raised).

Where is the error raised?  Is it good practice to override the method or is there a better way to do this all together?

I've tried overiding the builtin username in `AbstractUser`:

```
username = models.CharField(
    _('username'),
    max_length=150,
    unique=True,
    help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
    validators=[username_validator],
    error_messages={
        'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
    },
)
```

with

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

but unique must be true, which again throws the validationError before i need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the serializer so it looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator

class SeaUserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'role', 'gdpr', 'password',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'username': {
                'validators': [UnicodeUsernameValidator()],
            }
        }
```

This will remove the uniqueness validator from the serializer and leave the check up to you.

Comment: Thanks, in this case, what would the validator look like?